# QGraphicsItem and tab order

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

For some GUI application I use QMainWindow with different controls on it: QGraphicsScene + QGraphicsView , QPushButtons, QWidget.
Inside QGraphicsScene located a lot of different items type:

```
QGraphicsPolygonItem
QGraphicsTextItem
QGraphicsRectItem
```

But for me is most important is Polygon item, this item has those flags:

```
setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable, true);
setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);
```

I can select every item by mouse, but I need to change focus for those items by Tab.
How is it possible ?

SetTabOrder worked only with QGraphicsObjects.
I tried to solve this problem with QGraphicsView::focusNextPrevChild redefining

```
bool MyGraphicsView::focusNextPrevChild( bool next )
{
    QGraphicsPolygonItem *target;
    QGraphicsPolygonItem *current;

    if( scene()->focusItem() )
    {
        target = qgraphicsitem_cast<QGraphicsPolygonItem*>( scene()->focusItem() );

        bool is_focus_next=false;
        foreach( QGraphicsItem *item, scene()->items() )
        {
            current = qgraphicsitem_cast<QGraphicsPolygonItem*>( item );

  // set focus for next before selected
            if( current && is_focus_next )
            {
                item->setFocus( Qt::MouseFocusReason );
//                item->setSelected( true );
                is_focus_next  = false;
                break;
            }

  // searching for selected item 
            if( current && current == target )
            {
                is_focus_next = true;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But only first Tab worked, When I pressed Tab again focus has moved to other QWidget outside the QGraphicsView control.
Please, could you help me with Tab order focus for QGraphicsItem.

Thank you

EDIT: The final version, thanks to Steffen.

```
bool MyGraphicsView::focusNextPrevChild( bool next )
{
    QGraphicsPolygonItem *target;
    QGraphicsPolygonItem *current;

    if( scene()->focusItem() )
    {
        target = qgraphicsitem_cast<QGraphicsPolygonItem*>( scene()->focusItem() );

        bool is_focus_next=false;
        foreach( QGraphicsItem *item, scene()->items() )
        {
            current = qgraphicsitem_cast<QGraphicsPolygonItem*>( item );

  // set focus for next before selected
            if( current && is_focus_next )
            {
                item->setFocus( Qt::MouseFocusReason );
                return true;
            }

  // searching for selected item 
            if( current && current == target )
            {
                is_focus_next = true;
            }
        }

    }

return QGraphicsView::focusNextPrevChild(next);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return `true` to indicate that you actually found a widget. As you have no return statement at all at the moment, the behaviour is undefined. You can also add some logic to return `false` on the last element to allow the user to leave your `QGraphicsView` again.
See also the documentation for [QWidget::focusNextPrevChild()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qwidget.html#focusNextPrevChild).

Comment: Thank you, this small mistake (return true or false) have a big footprint.